# C Program for converting binary number to decimal isn't working

Tags: c, windows, binary, type-conversion, decimal

Following is a C program which i wrote for converting binary number into decimal, but it always gives output '0'. Can someone point out the mistake ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
int a=1/2,p=0,rem,n;
printf("Enter a binary number:");
scanf("%d",&n);
while(n!=0)
{
    a=a*2;
    rem=n%10;
    p=p+rem*a;
    n=n/10;
}
printf("Its decimal equivalent is %d",p);
}
```

Comment: `int a=1/2` is equivalent to`int a = 0`

Comment: yes, u r correct. So i did a modification & declared 'a' as float a=1/2; & still it doesn't works

Comment: Initialize `a = 1` and move `a=a*2;` to the last line of the loop. Since `a` is the power of 2 you are multiplying the binary digit by it should be `1, 2, 4, 8, etc`. Side note: your code would be easier to read with descriptive variable names (`power_of_2` instead of `a`, etc) and spaces (`a = a * 2;` not `a=a*2;`). Some people may argue that last point.

Comment: Thanx. This solved my problem. Also, i will keep that side note in my mind while coding

Answer (score 1):

when you divide integer numbers in c its round the solution.
so if you want to calc a/b as float you need casting like this `a/(float)b`